# Unable to download files from a certain website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, download

I've written some code in python to download files from a webpage. As i do not have any idea how to download files from any site so i could only scrape the file links from that site. If someone could help me achieve that I would be very grateful to him. Thanks a lot in advance.

Link to that site: [web_link](http://usda.mannlib.cornell.edu/MannUsda/viewDocumentInfo.do?documentID=1194)

Here is my try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get("http://usda.mannlib.cornell.edu/MannUsda/viewDocumentInfo.do?documentID=1194")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
for item in soup.select("#latest a"):
    print(item['href'])
```

Upon execution, the above script produces four different urls to those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with a standard library's [`urllib.request.urlretrieve()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve), but, since you are already using `requests`, you can re-use the session here (`download_file` was largely taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16696317/771848)):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def download_file(session, url):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]

    r = session.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)

    return local_filename


with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get("http://usda.mannlib.cornell.edu/MannUsda/viewDocumentInfo.do?documentID=1194")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("#latest a"):
        local_filename = download_file(session, item['href'])
        print(f"Downloaded {local_filename}")
```

Comment: Lucky to have you sir alecxe. It has been a while.  However, a little issue I'm facing when it hits the `print` line. It breaks there.

Comment: @Topto you have to use Python 3.6 to use string with prefix `f` as in example - but you can use old `print("Downloaded",  local_filename)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `request.get`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("http://usda.mannlib.cornell.edu/MannUsda/"
                        "viewDocumentInfo.do?documentID=1194")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
for item in soup.select("#latest a"):
    filename = item['href'].split('/')[-1]
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(item['href']).content)
```